# What's a word or phrase to describe a good book that I cannot put down when starting reading?

Tags: single-word-requests, books

What's a (big) word or phrase to describe a book that is so good that I cannot put down when I start to read it?

Comment: If you can’t put it down, you must be "gripping" it. ;)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

"Page-turner" is common. I've heard people say "potboiler," but i believe this inapt, as "potboiler" originally meant a work churned out merely to earn some lunch-money.

Comment: Sometimes called "Page-burner" as well.

Comment: Depending on the genre, "potboiler" _could_ be used, especially for something like a trashy bodice-ripper. It might not be "good" in any literary sense, but if it makes money for the author, that's good enough (see original meaning).

Comment: @PhilPerry, yes, but *potboiler* could serve just as well, if not better, for the sort of book where once you put it down, you can't pick it up.

Comment: LoL. James Bradley's "The Imperial Cruise."

Comment: @JonHanna, is there enough paper in the book to bring a small teakettle to a boil?

Comment: @Phil Perry. OALED at hand defines “potboiler” as “a book , a play etc. that is produced only to earn mone quickly” as Steven King already mentioned. It doesn’t seem to me to fit to the OP’s concept - a book that is so good that you cannot put down when you start to read it.

Comment: If the genre you like to read is trashy romance novels, you might not be able to put down such a book, even though most people would look down their noses at it. Some people _like_ potboilers.

Answer (score 13):

***Unputdownable*** has the exact meaning you described. Here's the [FreeDictionary definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unputdownable)

Comment: This word sounds like newspeak. Doubleplusgood!

Comment: @KevinWorkman Oh dear. I haven't actually heard anyone say "newspeak" since I read 1984.

Answer (score 12):

The phrase **compelling read** is often used to describe a book or article that is so good that one is drawn to finish it.

Answer (score 11):

engrossing, absorbing, captivating, gripping, fascinating, riveting, consuming,  addictive read

Answer (score 3):

“Page-turner” comes up top of mind.

Cambridge online English Dictionary defines “page-turner” as;

a book that is so exciting that you want to read it quickly.

Oxford online English Dictionary simply defines it as “an exciting book.

Merriam-Webster online Dictionary defines it as;

a book, story, etc., that is difficult to stop reading because it is so interesting

Kenkyu-sha Readers English Japanese Dictionary, the best-selling English Japanese dictionary published by Kenyusha Publishing defines “page-turner” as;

a book that is so interesting and exciting that you feel impatient to moving to the next page (turn pages).

As examples, I found the following phrase and sentences including "page-turner" and "turning pages" in the book review of Jeffrey Archer's "As the crow flies," which I picked to get an example of the use of "page-turner" at random;

- A certified page-turner - New York Daily News
- Archer plots with skill, and keeps you turning the pages - The Boston Globe
- Mr. Archer tells a story to keep you turning those pages - The Washington Post.

Besides, the New Yorker magazine has “Page-turner: On books and writing life” page as its regular columm.

Answer (score 2):

Oprah calls them "books you can't put down" (as in 25 books you can't...). Good Reads and Amazon advertises her choices using that phrase as well.

Answer (score 1):

When you are reading a [nail biter](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nail-biter) you cannot wait to see what is going to happen next and surely can't put book down.

> : something (such as a game or movie) that causes people to feel
>   nervous because the ending is not known until the final moment

Answer (score 1):

Relentless.
Take-no-prisoners.
Driven.
Fast/-paced.
(non-stop, etc.)...race to the end.
Rip-roaring.

Answer (score -1):

When you read a ***phenomenal*** book you want to read the book over and over again.
Trust me you'll know what kind of  book that is.