# Connotation of "dime novel"

Tags: word-usage

In the afterword of its novel ***Fahrenheit 451***, Ray Bradbury states that

> I didn't know it, but I was literally writing a dime novel.

However *dime novel* seems to have a negative connotation, according to the following definitions:

> a cheap melodramatic or sensational novel, usually in paperback and selling for ten cents, especially such an adventure novel popular c1850 to c1920.
>
> http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dime-novel
>
> Dime novel, a type of inexpensive, usually paperback, melodramatic novel of adventure popular in the United States roughly between 1860 and 1915
>
> http://global.britannica.com/art/dime-novel

[On this site](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/206792/is-there-a-word-for-a-cheap-page-turner/206796#206796), *dime novel* is used as an answer for the **opposite** of a gripping book.

The question is, if *dime novel* has such a bad connotation, why does Bradbury use that term to refer to [one of its most acclaimed work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fahrenheit_451#Reception)?

Comment: He may have simply meant that it ended up being sold for 10 cents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following extract may help undestand what he meant by "***[dime](http://latimesblogs.latimes.com/jacketcopy/2012/06/ray-bradbury-and-the-dime-at-a-time-typewriter-of-fahrenheit-451.html)***" novel:

> - In Los Angeles in the early 1950s, Ray Bradbury went in search of a peaceful place to work. "I had a large family at home," he said five decades later. They must have been a particularly lively bunch, because at the time it was just Ray, his wife Marguerite and two young children.
> - The writing refuge Bradbury found was in the basement of the Lawrence Clark Powell Library at UCLA -- and in fact, it wasn't all that quiet. "I heard this typing," he explained. "I went down in the basement of the UCLA library and by God there was a room with 12 typewriters in it that you could rent for 10 cents a half-hour. And there were eight or nine students in there working away like crazy."
> - ***So he went to the bank and returned with a bag of dimes. He plugged a dime into the machine, typed fast for 30 minutes, and then dropped another.***  When he took breaks, he went upstairs to the library, soaking in a book-loving ambience he was making forbidden in the fiction he was writing below. He took books off the shelves, finding quotes, then ran downstairs to write some more.  Nine days -- and $9.80 in dimes later -- he'd written "Fahrenheit 451." Almost.
> - What he'd finished there was "The Fireman," a short story published in Galaxy magazine in 1951. Later, he expanded the story into "Fahrenheit 451," which was published in paperback by Ballantine.
> - When "Fahrenheit 451" was selected as one of the books for the National Endowment for the Arts' Big Read project, Bradbury said, "My God, what a place to write that book!"

(Los Angeles Times)

Comment: Thanks! In retrospect, the "literally" gave it away, but I was confused by the beginning, the "I didn't know it" part...